htaccess rewriting a url to remove .php and to set a single variable as the end page not working
I am trying to get the following:
homepage.com/course-outline.php?training=az-104t00---microsoft-azure-administrator
To resolve to ideally something like this:
homepage.com/course-outline/az-104t00---microsoft-azure-administrator
or not my ideal scenario but also will work:
homepage.com/course-outline/training/az-104t00---microsoft-azure-administrator
I have tried the following:
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?course-outline/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) /course-outline.php?training=$1

And seperately this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/course-outline/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /course-outline.php?training=%1 [QSA,NC,NE,L]

Neither seem to do anything negative or positive. I have also tried multiple variables of the above also, seems like my regex is the issue but I am noit sure where I am going wrong.
If I could I would like it to resolve to homepage.com/course-outline/az-104t00---microsoft-azure-administrator.
I have also gone through https://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php and tried multiple tests on the live site and on  https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ but with no success.

The rule you have should work fine, https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=44ae2093-3be2-4a80-b2ea-78be21769c13

Not sure if your understanding of the process is correct to begin with though, your use of the phrase "resolve to" makes me think that might not be the case. So, to clarify - you are aware that this only rewrites incoming requests, but doesn't change the URLs you are using anywhere in your HTML, in your links - right?

I would agree that my understanding is not 100% but essentially what I am hoping to achieve is to have the variable display (to the user and SEO bots) as the directory page ideally with a .html extension not a dyanmic variable seen on the server side.  the link above does give a green tick on everything but does not change the output url. (Appreciate the help and fully accepting that I might be missing something)

"but does not change the output url" - as I said, what mod_rewrite does, is modify incoming requests. It doesn't change anything about the HTML you output. If you want something on your page to link to /course-outline/az-104t00---microsoft-azure-administrator, then you need to make that link href contain that value.

I am probably explaining it terribly, what I am trying to acieve is detailed on corz's blog under "not-so-simple rewriting ... flat links and more" https://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

stepping through it I think I am looking at it inverted, and have been testing the the server side againse the htaccess where I should be testing the user version and seeing it map to the server side, I think. Will post back it that is it.

Thank you for all the help. Yes it was a keyboard seat interface issue, just was looking at resolving it inverted. (That and a deep mistrust of regex.)
